# Find $P_2$ and $Q_2$ where $P_2\cdot A \cdot Q_2=B$ knowing that $P\cdot A \cdot Q= I_r $

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets assume we have three matrix $A$,$P$ and $Q$, where:

$$P\cdot A \cdot Q=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
I_r & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{array} } \right]
$$

Now find $P_2$ and $Q_2$ where:
$$P_2\cdot A \cdot Q_2=B$$

And $B$ is a known matrix, how can I do this?

---

Example: (This is the exercise the problem comes from)

$$A=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 2\\
-1 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & 4 & 2\\
\end{array} } \right]
$$

Find $P$ and $Q$ where $P\cdot A \cdot Q=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
I_r & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{array} } \right]
$

I start defining $A=M_{\beta_{k}}^{\beta_{k}}(f)$

Then I find $Q=M_{\beta}^{\beta_{k}}=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array} } \right]$ and $P=M_{\beta_{k}}^{\beta^{'}}=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -4/3 & 1/3\\
0 & -1/3 & 1/3\\
1 & 4/3 & -1/3\\
\end{array} } \right]$

Where $\beta = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(-2,-1,1)\}$ and $\beta^{'}=\{(1,-1,1),(0,1,4),(1,0,0)\}$

Now find $P_2$ and $Q_2$ where:

$P_2\cdot A \cdot Q_2=B=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
\end{array} } \right]$

Those 2 matrices exist as $rg(A)=rg(B)$, how to find them?

Comment: If you find  $P_3BQ_3=\begin{bmatrix}I_r & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ then it is straigthforward from $P_3BQ_3=PAQ$.

Comment: Can I define $B=M_{\beta_{k}}^{\beta_{k}}(f)$ after defining $A=M_{\beta_{k}}^{\beta_{k}}(f)$? Or is it another function and $B=M_{\beta_{k}}^{\beta_{k}}(g)$?

Comment: For the approach that you’re taking, assume that $A$ and $B$ represent the same map, but with expressed w/r different pairs of bases.